# Maxthon Browser 5 on Ubuntu?

Tags: browser

Is there a way to get the [MX5](http://www.maxthon.com/) Browser on Ubuntu? if yes how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MX 5 is not in the Ubuntu Repositories.
MX 5 is not supported software.

Use **at your own risk**.

Go to
http://www.maxthon.com/blog/maxthon-expands-its-suite-of-high-performance-web-browsers-to-linux/ and download the appropriate .deb file. 1.0.5 is currently the latest available.

Use dpkg to install the .deb

```
sudo dpkg --install /path/to/file.deb
```